# Populating Observable with initail value while listing to chnages

Tags: angular, observable

I have an Observable that needs to have an initial value on creation but it also needs to listen to events and in case of change it should re-populate with data from the server. Seems simple enough but I can't find an elegant way of doing this.

So this is the scenario, I have a select in a form that is bound to an async array Observable like so:

```
<mat-select>               
    <mat-option *ngFor="let unit of units$ | async"
        [value]="unit.unitCode">
        {{ unit.unitCode }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

when the component is first initialized it could be in either 1 of 2 states:

- A record from the DB, where I already have valid data for the form filed.
- A new record where the units$ should be populated only after another filed gets its value.

In either case, changing the value of that other filed should fetch new values for the units$.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    if (this.form.controls['itemID'].value) {
        this.units$ = of([Object.assign(new Unit(), {
            unitCode: 'U1'
        })]);
    }

    this.units$ = this.form.controls['itemID'].valueChanges
        .pipe(
        switchMap((term: number ) => {
            return this.service.getById(term);
        }));
}
```

Of-course, doing it like this means that the initial value I assigned to the units$ will not be there since I reassigned the Observable.
What I am actually looking for in a way to do something similar to `startWith` without actually calling the service, but still get an Observable which is listing to changes.

An example of the wanted behavior: The component holds a record from the DB.

1. Unless the user changes 'itemID' there is no reason to get data from the service.
2. The units$ has a 'unit' array with just the one unit that is on the record.
3. If the user changes 'itemID', units$ should fetch new values from the service.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a perfect use case for using the **[`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html)** operator.

Here, give this a try:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.units$ = this.form.controls['itemID'].valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith([Object.assign(new Unit(), {
        unitCode: 'U1'
      })]),
      switchMap((term: number) => this.service.getById(term)));
}
```

Haven't tested it out. But don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.

Let me know if it doesn't :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will emit the data I want to receive, 1) it emits the wrong data, so the value the subscriber will get wrong. 2) I don't to get the data from the service when I already know what data the observable, should have. I am adding an example to the question, maybe it will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html), which is a type of an observable. Unlike a regular observable, you can manually push data into it using it's `next()` method. Something like this:

```
units$ = new Subject<[]>();

ngOnInit(): void { 
    if (this.form.controls['itemID'].value) {
        this.units$.next([Object.assign(new Unit(), {
            unitCode: 'U1'
        })]);
    }

    this.form.controls['itemID'].valueChanges
        .pipe(
        switchMap((term: number ) => {
            this.units$.next(this.service.getById(term));
        }));
}
```

Comment: I tried that, my service is returning an Observable which can't be assigned to the next. Manipulating the Observable with subscribe causes other errors regarding the return type of the `switchMap`, if you can change your code to show how to work with Observable from the service I would love to try it.